# Compute $\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x-\cos x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

> Compute
>
> $$\int \frac{\sin x+\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{\sin x-\cos x}}\,\mathrm dx$$

---

Let $t=\tan\frac x2$, then

$$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2},\; \cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\; \mathrm dx =\frac{2\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}.$$

then, ..

Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  If $u=\sin x-\cos x$, then $du = (\cos x+\sin x)dx$.

Comment: really grateful for your help